# Let $(G,*,e)$ be a group, $a\in G$. Define $g\circ h=g*a*h$ for all $g,h\in G$. Prove $(G,\circ)$ is a group and give the neutral element.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $(G,*,e)$ is a group and $a \in G$. Define the operation $$ g\circ h=g*a*h$$

for all $g,h\in G$, prove that $(G,\circ)$ is a group and give the neutral element of the group.

My question is, without knowing the operation $*$ of the first group, can I just use it ($*$) to prove the new one?

I started with how we usually prove these kind of things with the group axioms but I realised if it were that easy this would be from our professor (he likes to see us hurt, I think lol). And I'm not quite sure how this would work tbh because there is no $e$ in the new group $(G,\circ)$.

Comment: Yes you can: you have available the [properties of Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) for $*$.

Comment: The map $g \mapsto g*a$ is an isomorphism $(G,\circ,a^{-1}) \to (G,*,e)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $*$ be denoted by concatenation. Fix $a\in G$.

*Closure:*

This follows from closure of $(G,*,e)$; indeed, for any $g,h\in G$, we have $g\circ h=gah\in G$.

*Associativity:*

Let $f,g,h\in G$. Then

$$\begin{align}
f\circ (g\circ h)&=f\circ(gah)\\
&=fa(gah)\\
&=(fag)ah\\
&=(f\circ g)ah\\
&=(f\circ g)\circ h.
\end{align}$$

*Identity:*

**Lemma:** The identity $1$ of a group $H$ is the only idempotent in $H$.

*Proof:* Let $x^2=x$. Then $1x=x=xx$, so, multiplying on the right by $x^{-1}$, we get $1=x$.$\square$

Now suppose $k\circ k=k\in G$. Then $kak=k$, so that $ak=e$. Then $k=a^{-1}$. Hence the identity *would be* $a^{-1}$ (where the inverse is taken with respect to $*$). Let's check: for all $g\in G$, we have

$$\begin{align}
g\circ( a^{-1})&=gaa^{-1}\\
&=g\\
&=a^{-1}ag\\
&=(a^{-1})\circ g.
\end{align}$$

So it checks out.

*Inverses:*

Let $g\in G$. Then if $g\circ h=a^{-1}$ for some $h\in G$, we have $gah=a^{-1}$, so that $h=(ga)^{-1}a^{-1}=a^{-1}g^{-1}a^{-1}$; by uniqueness of inverses, then, $g^{-1}$ (with respect to $\circ$) is $a^{-1}g^{-1}a^{-1}$ (where the inverses are taken with respect to $*$).

Comment: The part with identity is incorrect because it uses the fact that the new structure is a group which you are in the middle of proving.

Comment: Good point, @Adayah; well spotted! Thank you! I have edited my answer accordingly.